# F# Interesting Behavior of Curried Function

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I have a function

```
// Will perform a given function twice
let twice f = (fun x -> f (f x))
```

Then I have something like.

```
// Take x add 1
let f x = x+1
```

Depending on how I call twice it behaves differently do to left associativity.

```
(twice (twice (twice (twice f)))) 0;; // Outputs 16
twice twice twice twice f 0;; // Outputs 65536
```

If I add another twice my program does a StackOverflow, but so far it seems to behave without a pattern, which drives me crazy.

Let k be the number of times `twice` is called.

Un-curried is 2^k to get the answer.

Curried is extremely odd. **Hypothesis 1:** When the number of calls is less than 4 it looks like 2^(2^(k-1)), but when k is 4 it behaves like 2^(2^k)

Does anyone see the pattern? Or can you run it past k = 4 to prove it?

Comment: While this is an interesting puzzle I don't believe this is the appropriate forum to share this sort of thing.  Vote to close.

Comment: "I'll post the answer in 24hrs if nobody has it.  Good luck!"  There are sites for programming puzzles; StackOverflow is not such a site.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Absolutely agree. Mike John, please edit your question. This question was a good question but the puzzle challenge ruined it. One can simply argue: "if you give us a puzzle after give us a question, it's assumed that you already have the answer. why bother asking?".

Comment: Actually I didn't know the answer when I posted, that is why the challenge is on the EDIT section. Anyway I will correct the question, asap.

Comment: Ok--so it's not a puzzle question now.  I'd still love to know how such a use case would come up in actual development.  If _twice_ is meant to be recursive it's not. If _twice_ is meant to use function composition, as far as I can tell, it doesn't.  As far as I can tell, you're basically asking why nonsense code doesn't work.

Comment: Who said it has to come up in development? Although it can. Who said a question has to have more purpose than to understand an interesting behavior? Then again, it is normal for misunderstood things to be nonsense to some. PS I never said the code didn't work. I only found it worth sharing that same code behaves differently when called differently and if it had a pattern. Take care...

Answer (score 3):

This is simple precedence rules behaving weirdly  (the hint is 65536=2^16).  In the second case you are actually creating an exponential number of calls to f rather than the linear increase you expected.

When you expand one layer on the second case you get

```
twice twice twice (twice twice twice (f)) 0
```

and the number of terms will grow exponentially as you write more `twice`

Comment: Yup, it has to do with functions being associated to the left, right?

Comment: Yes, this is just how F# handles things written in this sort of order.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's all about associativity. When you write,

```
let x1 = twice twice twice twice f 0
```

It's equal to

```
let x11 = (((twice twice) twice) twice) f 0
```

This leads to exponential growth of call order: each `twice` call is supposed to call `f x` two times. Instead, it recursively calls itself, and **only the most inner call** would invoke `f`.

You may look at the prototype of the function:

```
let y1: ( _ -> _ -> int) = twice twice twice twice
// val y1: ((int -> int) -> int -> int)
```

The minimal code to make the associativity work well would be:

```
// note we need to specify a type here
let y2: ( _ -> _ -> int) = twice >> twice >> twice >> twice
// the same with all arguments
let x2 = (twice >> twice >> twice >> twice) f 0
```

or

```
let y3 = f |> twice |> twice |> twice |> twice
let x3 = (f |> twice |> twice |> twice |> twice) 0
```

Comment: It seems strange to me. Why it recurse? let twice f = f >> f. let t1 = twice twice so t1 returns twice >> twice. let t2 = twice >> twice. Why t1 behaves differently than t2?

Comment: @tomasK `twice >> ... >> twice` and `twice ... twice` grow differently (linear and exponential, respectively). They get equal values only if applied two times exactly because `2*2 = 2^2`.

Comment: Sure result is clear, but I have problem to imagine how and why it is called in exp. manner. I tried to point out that twice twice gives in result twice >> twice, so I do not see why it grows exponential in this case, when it looks virtually same as your linear case twice >> twice.